# How to set "-aspectpath" for the FreeFair AspectJ Gradle Plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, aspectj, freefair-aspectj

I am trying to use an AspectJ Annotation that is in a Library, that I am pulling into my project. My project uses Gradle, so I am attempting to use [FreeFair AspectJ Gradle Plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=freefair+aspectj).

I need to be able to set the AspectJ *-aspectpath* argument, to the Library Dependency that Gradle is pulling in.

FreeFair, does not seem to have much [Documentation](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/tree/3.5.1/aspectj-plugin), mainly just [Sample Code](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/blob/3.5.1/examples/aspectj).

In their sample code, I see that I can use this to set the *-aspectpath* to a local "project":

```
aspect project(":aspectj:aspect")
```

Does anyone know how to set the *-aspectpath* to an external library dependency?

I created an example Project and put it on GitHub: [freefair-aspectpath-external-library](https://github.com/BrandonDudek/freefair-aspectpath-external-library).

- *Note:* I am using *io.freefair.gradle:aspectj-plugin* version **2.9.5** because my project is stuck using Gradle version **4.10.3**.

**Update:** I have created a bug for this: https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/46

Comment: Have you tried raising an issue at the GitHub site and asking the author directly?

Comment: GitHub tickets are not just about bugs, they can be about documentation issues too. And that plugin definitely has some serious documentation issues. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@larsgrefer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574494/larsgrefer), who provided the answer in the GitHub Issue ([46](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/46)).

> For the *io.freefair.aspectj.compile-time-weaving* plugin 2.9.5 the configuration is named "**aspects**" instead of "aspect".

The following fixed the issue:

```
aspects project(":aspectj:aspect")
```

The full build file resembles:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        // 2.9.5 for use with Gradle 4.10.3.
        classpath "io.freefair.gradle:aspectj-plugin:2.9.5"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

apply plugin: "io.freefair.aspectj.compile-time-weaving"
aspectj.version = '1.9.3'

group 'xyz.swatt'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    ///// SWATT ///// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xyz.swatt/swatt
    compile group: 'xyz.swatt', name: 'swatt', version: '1.12.0'
    aspect "xyz.swatt:swatt:1.12.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`aspect` is a plain old gradle configuration.

This means you can use all the notations described here:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_types.html#dependency_types
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

```groovy
dependencies {
    aspect project(":my-aspect")
    aspect "com.example.foo:bar-aspect:1.0.0"
    aspect file("foo.jar")
}
```